# Extract layer from the images

Tags: adobe, extract, exploit

I have a image and I want to extract a particular portion of a whole image.
what can I do for? 
[image: I want to extract the taj Mahal from this image.]

I want to extract the taj Mahal from this image.

Answer (score 0):

This image appears to be a JPEG. JPEG images do not contain layers. Your best bet is going to be to start with a better image. Even then, you'll almost certainly need to paint in portions. If this is really the only image you can find at the correct angle then you'll be doing a lot of hand editing to get what you want.

Try: https://www.google.com/search?q=taj+Mahal&tbm=isch